# IIS - Configuração do gerenciador para programação ASP

Tags: iis

Depois de um bom e longo trabalho para instalar o IIS no Windows 10, quando vou adicionar um site, no bloco Associação e no campo Tipo, não aparece o item http onde é possível colocar a porta e o nome do host. Acho que falta algum módulo. Alguém sabe dizer qual ou faltou algum recurso?

Complementando: note que consta o http na primeira tela e na sua edição está sumido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual a versão do IIS? Você pode descrever o que você está tentando fazer, incluindo o caminho no Gerenciador de Serviços da Internet que você está tentando traçar para incluir criar um site? Se sim, edita sua pergunta e torne-a mais descritiva, deste modo, vai atrair mais pessoas tentando ajudar.

Comment: A versão do IIS é a 10.0.0.0 e do console do gerenciador é 3.0 versão 1607. Independentemente do caminho que coloco o lugar do site, não aparece o http no tipo.

Comment: Dá uma olhada [***nisto aqui***](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/323972/how-to-set-up-your-first-iis-web-site). Se assemelha ao que você está tentando fazer?

Comment: É basicamente isso, mas no campo tipo aparecem 4 tipos: net.tcp, net.pipe, net.msmq e msmq.formatname. Nada de http onde tem a porta.

Answer (score -1):

Voce deve clicar em Site e botao Direito e Adicionar Site e nesta tela voce cria o site e tem a opção de colocar a porta que voce quer usar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entendi, veja se estas opções estao marcadas em sua instalação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Faço isso mas onde está o http só aparece 4 itens: net.tcp, net.pipe, net.msmq e msmq.formatname.

Comment: Estão todas marcadas

Answer (score -1):

Você vai ter que adicionar um novo [*binding*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding) nessa situação.

De acordo com a documentação (o conteúdo não está disponível em Português, então, perdoe qualquer erro):

[***Como adicionar informações de vínculos (binding information) ao seu site***](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding)

1. Abra o "Gerenciador de Serviços da Internet":
   [...]

   - Se estiver usando Windows 8 ou Windows 8.1 *[ou Windows 10, desde que não esteja organizado por categoria]*:
   - Mantenha pressionada a tecla Windows, pressione X, e clique em "Painel de Controle".
   - Clique em "**Ferramentas administrativas**", e então dê duplo-clique em "**Gerenciador de Serviços de Informação da Internet (IIS)**".
2. Na aba "**Conexões**", expanda o nome do servidor (server name), expanda "**Sites**", e então clique no site em que você quer configurar as associações (bindings).
3. Na aba "**Ações**", clique "**Associações...**" (Bindings...)
4. Na caixa de diálogo "**Associações do Site**" (Site Bindings), clique "**Adicionar...**"

[image: Add Site Binding dialog box]

5. Na caixa de diálogo "**Adicionar Associação Ao Site**", adicione as informações da associação, e então clique "**OK**".

[image: Site Bindings dialog box]

Comment: Cheguei a entrar nesta opção, aqui está como Associações, mas na lista do type não aparece o http. No quadro ele até aparece com a porta 80, mas se edito, o http some.

Comment: Eu só editei para incluir a informação que você forneceu, mas não achei novidade qualquer na documentação.